# Receipt validation errors on submission to Mac app store

Tags: macos, swift, mac-app-store, receipt-validation

On Mac App Store submission my app get rejected with following explanation:-

> "With a valid receipt installed, the app quits on launch. The Console reports the app "`Exited with exit code: 173`" and the OS states the app "`is damaged and can't be opened`". This generally indicates that the app is not verifying its receipt correctly."

I do not do any receipt validation in my code at all so what can I do to fix this? It happens only on review, not on my side. This is simple swift ui + Objective-C+ some C++ for logic OS X application. With other app, (Objective-C + CPP) everything was alright.

Comment: Are you really sure you don't have any receipt checking code? Exiting with code 173 seems very unlikely without it.

Comment: I am sure I do not do receipt checking code. It is basically a new swift template with some controls added. Only if it is somehow built-in by Xcode?

Comment: Then the only explanation I have is that the review ran another app by mistake, or that s/he mistakenly picked this rejection criteria instead of another.

Comment: Actually it is not first submission. Previous reviewer asked to remove some items from menu, so at least once it run in review environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After all this happened to be bug on the reviewer side. I asked to reexamine my app in Resolution center and it passed the review. Thanks to @Aderstedt I felt more confident that it's not my bug.

Comment: I'm currently receiving this same issue/response from the reviewers, and just asked for them to review it again. I don't have any receipt checking/validation code going on either.